# No ObservableObject of type XXX found just inside a notification observer

Tags: swiftui

I have a class like this:

```
class GlobalVariables: ObservableObject {
  @Published var aaa = AAA()
  @Published var bbb = BBB()
  @Published var ccc = CCC()
}
```

When I want to access that, I add this to a view:

```
@EnvironmentObject var globalVariables : GlobalVariables
```

and that's it.

So, I did that to my view called `MyView`.

and I am happy. I can access globalVariables almost anywhere inside `MyView`.

But, and there is always a but, `MyView` contains this method:

```
  func initNotification() {
   let gv = globalVariables // 1
    NotificationCenter.default
      .addObserver(forName: .runOnDetectedObject,
                   object: nil,
                   queue: OperationQueue.main,
                   using: {notification in
                      globalVariables.aaa(object:myObj)) // 2
                   })
  }
```

//1 and //2 compile fine, but when I run, both lines crash with

> Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type GlobalVariables found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for GlobalVariables may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

I have this on MyApp.swift

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
        .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        .environmentObject(GlobalVariables())
    }
  }
```

The view I am having the problem is not ContentView()

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

But, you have to pass the `EnvironmentObject` down.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @EnvironmentObject var globalVariables : GlobalVariables

    var body: some View {
        MyView().environmentObject(globalVariables)
    }
}
```

It usually only works for about 2-3 layers. If you go any deeper than that it is pretty buggy.

Comment: I think the problem is that, is how deep I am going. I am converting that into a singleton. Makes more sense for the class. Thanks.